# «Бывший сельский голова Антонина Ивановна ...» Верно ли употребление мужского рода?

Tags: род

«Бывший сельский голова Антонина Ивановна ...» Верно ли употребление мужского рода по отношению к должности, занимаемой женщиной?

Answer (score 1):

Сельский голова́ - это должность. Здесь слово ГОЛОВА мужского рода, стоящее рядом с ним прилагательное СЕЛЬСКИЙ тоже. Слово БЫВШИЙ поэтому согласуется со словосочетанием СЕЛЬСКИЙ ГОЛОВА также в мужском роде:

***Бывший сельский голова Антонина Ивановна (лучше использовать фамилию)...***

[Розенталь Д.Э.](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm):

При сочетании нарицательного имени и собственного имени лица определение согласуется с ближайшим из существительных, например: *внимательный врач Петрова – врач Петрова, внимательная к больным.*